# Perpendicular Vectors find x

Tags: vectors

My Higher maths question booklet has this question and I am rather stuck with it. I have done one similar before I just cannot remember and have no idea now.

```
      Two vectors **a** and **b** are perpendicular.
      **a** = i – 2j + xk and **b** = xi + 3j + xk
      Find and verify any possible values of x.
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:
$\vec a \perp \vec b \Leftrightarrow \vec a \cdot \vec b = a_x b_x + a_y b_y + a_z c_z = 0$

Answer (score 0):

compute the dot-product:$$(i-2j+xk)\cdot
 (xi+3j+xk)=x-6+x^2$$

Comment: yes that is what i meant